# "Whomever runs it's" or "whomever runs its"?

Tags: possessives, grammatical-case, noun-phrases, saxon-genitive, whoever-vs-whomever

I know that "its" is the possessive form of "it", but does this rule apply to the possessive form of phrases ending in "it"?  Should I say, "the program runs on whomever runs its computer" or "the program runs on whomever runs it's computer" (also I hope I'm right that that should be "whomever" and not "whoever")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE:** Ignore this first bit and skip down to the **EDIT** section for the right answer.  I misread the sentence on first (and second, and third) reading.

---

The closest sentence with correct grammar (but not sense) that matches your own is:

> The program runs on **whoever** runs **its** computer.

Because the object of the preposition *on* is not **whomever*, which is wrong, but rather the entire clause *whoever runs its computer*, in which *whoever* acts as the subject of the verb *runs*.  The proximity of *on* is a red herring — or strange attractor, depending on which metaphor you prefer.

Since you can replace *its* with *his* — and not with *it is* — this shows that *its* must be correct.

However, all that said and done, I am unconvinced that this sentence makes sense.  I bet you want:

> The program runs on the computer of whoever runs it.

Because I don’t think it runs on people, but rather on computers.

Maybe you could almost get away with:

> The program runs on whosever computer runs it.

But that seems a bit off, too.

---

### EDIT

Now I see what you were going for!  You were trying to use the Saxon genitive on the entire noun phrase:

> The program runs on (whoever runs it)’s computer.

Which is just like:

> The program runs on (the person who runs it)’s computer.

That way it would work the same way as these do:

> It’s (the Queen of England)’s castle.
>   It’s (the man at the door)’s hat.
>   It’s [(my wife and I)’s dinner](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner?rq=1).
>   He’s (all of those kids)’ friend.
>   He’s [(all of us)’s friend](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4994/all-of-uss-friend?rq=1).

Unfortunately, without parentheses, people will too easily misread it, as in fact did I the first few times through it.

While there is certainly some sense in what you say, it if nothing else garden-paths to the wrong *it’s*, which makes it look like a mistake even when it isn’t.

I’d still say it runs on the computer of whoever runs it myself, just to make sure.

Comment: Analysis iffy here. According to one source, '_I don't know who did that._ (nominative because even though 'who' is the object of 'know', it is the subject of 'did' and it is loyal to the relative clause)' … Nicky.
However, Fowler gives an example of the form

“Do not follow he who breaks the law.” 

saying (I’m sure correctly) that the correct version is 

“Do not follow him who breaks the law.”

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Mmm, what? Nothing you’ve written contradicts anything I have.  We are not talking about a “he who” or a “him whom” sort of case: it is a *whoever* vs. *whomever* case, which is different from what you have offered.  My analysis is certainly correct that when the object of the preposition is **an entire clause**, the subject of that clause is still in subject case. You may ask whomever you please, or even whoever pleases you, and it will get the same answer.

Comment: Wouldn't 'remaining loyal to the relative clause' require **he** who breaks the law?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No. **Let *him who* is without sin cast the first stone.**  Although there *him* is the object of *let*, it is *who* who is the subject of *is*.  Same idea with yours. Each to his own: *him* goes with *let* but *who* goes with *is*. Otherwise if you deleted “who is without sin” you would have incorrect grammar, which is the test with these things, since it would leave you with “let *he cast the first stone”, which is completely wrong.

Comment: I can't see a vast difference in structure between “Do not follow whoever breaks the law.” and “Do not follow him who breaks the law.” But one takes the subject case, one the object. Admittedly, I have seen an analysis that claims that 'whoever' is a mixed object/subject form, but that looks like a fudge to me. Of course, a noun would fulfil both roles without giving rise to much concern: “Do not follow a/the man who breaks the law.”

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The short story is because “who breaks the law” is um, detachable, like “who is without sin”.  It branches off the thing to its left, but does not govern that thing.

Comment: Have you a reference or two discussing this 'detachableness' rule? I'd love to see how German say handles the situation - does the man become dem (or den) Mann, or der Mann? Assuming they permit this sort of construction.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help with deciding what case to use for the relative pronoun. Whether or not a relative pronoun should be in the objective or in the nominative case is determined by the relative pronoun's function within its relative clause. Some examples:

> the girl who loves me

Here, *who* is the subject of the verb *loves* in the relative clause *who loves me*; therefore one uses the nominative case, *who*, not the objective case, *whom*. It doesn't matter what is the function in the sentence of the relative pronoun's referent, *girl* . Thus,

> The girl who loves me loves another as well.

and

> I love the girl who loves me.

In the first example the referent is the subject of the verb of the sentence; in the second it is the object of the verb *love*. It doesn't make any difference.

---

> the girl whom I love

Here, *whom* is the object of the verb *love* in the relative clause *whom I love*; 
therefore one uses the objective case, *whom*, not the nominative case, *who*. It doesn't matter what is the function in the sentence of the relative pronoun's referent, *girl* . Thus,

> The girl whom I love loves another.

and

> Another loves the girl whom I love.

In the first example the referent is the subject of the verb of the sentence; in the second it is the object of the verb *loves*. Again, it doesn't make any difference.

Some people get a little baffled when, instead of noun referents, there are pronoun referents, but it still works the same way:

> The girl who loves me loves another as well. >> She who loves me loves
>   another as well.
>
> I love the girl who loves me. >> I love her who loves me.
>
> The girl whom I love loves another. >> She whom I love loves another.
>
> Another loves the girl whom I love. >> Another loves her whom I love.

But what really confuses people is when the relative pronoun has no explicit referent, which has been omitted by a kind of ellipsis, as it were:

> Whoever loves me loves another as well.
>
> I love whoever loves me.
>
> Whomever I love loves another.
>
> Another loves whomever I love.

In such cases, we say that the entire relative clause functions in the sentence as its relative pronoun's absent pronoun referent would have. This confuses people who then try to put the relative pronoun in the same case that its "missing" pronoun referent would have had.

Comment: So it should be "whoever". Dang.