# "your and Mr X's publication" vs. "you and Mr X's publication"

Tags: conjunctions, possessives, personal-pronouns, coordinating-conjunctions, saxon-genitive

> I came across your and Mr X's publication

or

> I came across you and Mr X's publication

Comment: There is also "I came across yours and Mr. X's publication".

Comment: Related: [My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMOS 16th edition says in 7.22 that it depends on whether you mean the nouns as a single unit or as discrete units; that is, whether the object possessed is the same or different for those two nouns. Since you're talking about two authors responsible for a single publication, not two authors of multiple publications, the nouns are a single unit. "I came across you and Mr. X's publication" is correct.

But there's no question that it is awkward because it's in the second person. (Compare to this third-person sentence: "I came across Dan and Steve's publication.") Reworking the sentence is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Add another vote for reworking. Any of the options that preserve the original word order sound awkward.

Answer (score 10):

"You" sounds wrong and "your" awkward.  Turn it around: I came across "Charlie Manson reconsidered" by you and Mr. X.

Answer (score 1):

According to Garner's Modern American Usage by Bryan A. Garner, correct usage would be, "'Thanks, Dad....It was through *your's* [read *your*] and Mom's hard work and guidance that I have come this far.' Ginny Rudy, "Traveling in Memory of Dad," *Pitt. Post-Gaz*., 26 Dec. 2000, at E3." (Here, the read version, which is *your,* is correct).

Answer (score -2):

Singular unit when both parties are part of a single topic, transaction, etc.

example: 'You and your brothers'

You wouldn't say 'Yours and your brothers' Two many pocessions-there are not multiples of 'You'. Brothers is showing ownership of the 'subject'. You can't both have plural ownerships hence the word 'and'