# What is the proper way to say possesive with "person X" and self?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, compound-possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner)

I've never known what the proper way to use a sentence in which you and a specific person (as in you can't just say "our" because you want to specify who) possess something.  Is it "Julie's and mine", "Mine and Julies", "Julie and my"...?

For instance,
"Julie and my favorite band is Eluveitie."
"That sandwich is Ben and mine."

They all sound a bit strange, which is the correct way to say this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My wife and I's](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner) or [What possessives are used for Mutual first-person ownership](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8520/what-possessive-forms-are-used-for-mutual-1st-person-ownership) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Julie's and mine" and "mine and Julie's" (note apostrophe) are both correct for the predicate possessive form, "Julie's and my" for the simple possessive form.

Comment: Right answer, but just to note that the difference between "my" and "mine" isn't subject/object case - it's whether the possessive is functioning as a determiner ("my sheep/Julie's and my sheep") or a full-blown pronoun ("mine/Julie's and mine"). Either can occur in subject or object position ("Do you like Julie's and my favorite band?", "Ben's and mine is the sandwich next to yours").

Comment: @psmears: Thanks; I've rephrased my answer in terms of the form of the pronoun being used.

Comment: Note: "mine and Julie's" is indeed grammatical. However, etiquette and common courtesy dictate that you should always name yourself last. Thus depending on your context, you may still wish to avoid "mine and Julie's", albeit grammatically correct.