# Multiple people possession

Tags: word-choice, compound-possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “my wife and I's” correct, or should it be “my wife's and my”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/is-my-wife-and-is-correct-or-should-it-be-my-wifes-and-my)
>   [Preferred way to apostrophise in case of dual or multiple ownership by distinct entities?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/preferred-way-to-apostrophise-in-case-of-dual-or-multiple-ownership-by-distinct-e)

What is the correct grammar to use in a phrase like "Chris' and Claire's email addresses"? Is it correct to add the apostrophe to each owner in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the fact that OP's example specifies **addresses** in the plural means that Chris *and* Claire have separate email addresses.

Thus the phrase is actually a contraction of *"Chris' email address and Claire's email address"*, so both apostrophes are valid (I personally would write *Chris's*, but opinions may differ on that).

Comment: Yes, I was referring to separate email addresses. As a Computer Scientist I shouldn't be so ambiguous!

I think I will start using the "Chris's" form based on the couple of questions here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/when-did-it-become-correct-to-add-an-s-to-a-singular-possessive-already-ending