# How do I use possessive when talking about a book written by two authors?

Tags: compound-possessives

Tom DeMarco and Timothy Lister are two authors of *Peopleware*. When talking or writing about the book, do I have to write:

> Have you read Tom DeMarco and Timothy Lister's *Peopleware*?

or:

> Have you read Tom DeMarco**'s** and Timothy Lister's *Peopleware*?

Comment: Probably the first form, and consider dropping the first names. "Have you read DeMarco and Lister's Peopleware?"

Comment: Can you please expand on this in a form of an answer? Also, your remark about dropping first names is interesting: indeed, I've usually seen sentences like this using family names only. What is the reason?

Comment: Probably just brevity, and to show that the speaker is very familiar with a work. It's very common when discussing literature - "have you read much Tolstoy?"

Comment: Also: [Preferred way to apostrophise in case of dual or multiple ownership by distinct entities](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/preferred-way-to-apostrophise-in-case-of-dual-or-multiple-ownership-by-distinct-e) and more can be found.

Comment: @benshepherd: certainly not the first form, since that one is asking me if I have read any works of Tom DeMarco and *Peopleware* written by Timothy Lister alone.

Comment: Hmm. You're probably correct, but I think it [the double-possessive] sounds too fussy in everyday speech. I prefer my quote above, as I think it sounds more natural. DeMarco-and-Lister is an easier entity to process than Tom-DeMarco-and-Timothy-Lister.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: on the other hand, [according to the duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/11852/10307): “if possession is joint, only the last possessor has possessive inflection”. As I understand it, in a case of a book, the possession is joint. The situation would be different if I was talking about books written by DeMarco and, at the same time, books written by Lister.