# Multiple possessives of a single object linked by 'or'

Tags: disjunction, compound-possessives

In the sentence, 'NCA offers a tool to measure a country's or region's natural capital', are one or both of country and region possessive (country's or region's vs. country or region's)? Ownership is a bit ambiguous because of the inclusive 'or'.

Comment: is this your own sentence? It would sound better if it were rephrased: *NCA offers a tool that measures the natural capitals of countries and regions.*

Comment: I had an answer, but it was downvoted with no reason given. So now there is no answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preferred way to apostrophise in case of dual or multiple ownership by distinct entities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/preferred-way-to-apostrophise-in-case-of-dual-or-multiple-ownership-by-distinct)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Nikki's and Alice's X" vs. "Nikki and Alice's X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x)

Comment: Not a duplicate, unless somebody can identify an answer that addresses the case of something belonging to or associated with *one* of two (or more) entities; viz., X ***or*** Y.

Comment: Consider: “What’s that orange thing on the floor?” / “It’s either the cat or the dog’s toy.” — OK, so there are two possibilities.  One possibility is that the thing is the dog’s toy.  What’s the other possibility:  might it be the cat’s toy, or might it be ***the cat**?*  If it might be the cat’s toy, then we need to say “It’s either the ***cat’s*** or the dog’s toy.” to remove the ambiguity.  And, sure, we can reword it clumsily (“It’s a toy belonging to either the cat or the dog.” or “It’s either the cat’s toy or the dog’s toy.”); but why should we?

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence is "NCA offers a tool to measure a country or region's natural capital," as this situation is analogous to the question in [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/preferred-way-to-apostrophise-in-case-of-dual-or-multiple-ownership-by-distinct).

Comment: The linked post is irrelevant because it talks about “X ***and*** Y”, and *this* question is about “X ***or*** Y”.

Comment: I don't know that it is entirely irrelevant though. I think the same basic structure applies with any possessive nouns linked by a conjunction.

Comment: Did you see  [my comment on the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/470203/26083#comment1138309_470203)?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not. My brain is not functioning at the highest of levels this morning.