# Is this sentence grammatically correct? Thank you

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrases, compound-possessives

I was extremely surprised and am grateful for you all celebrating Mallory’s and my special day.

Comment: Hello, welcome to English Language and Usage SE! Please be aware that proofreading questions are not [on-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site. We will be able to answer your question if you can specify a particular part of the sentence (grammar or word usage) that you are unsure about.

Comment: If the part you are unsure about is "Mallory's and my," you might find the answers to the following question useful: [What possessive forms are used for mutual 1st person ownership?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8520)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

> I was extremely surprised and am grateful for you all celebrating
>   Mallory’s and my special day.

It is incorrect.

You switch verb tense from past tense to present tense: *was surprised* to *am*

Keep *am* by making it a Compound Sentence.

"Mallory’s and my special day" = correct =

> When on of the words showing joint possession is a pronoun, both words
>   should be possessive in form: **Peggy's and my bookcase** [*not Peggy and
>   my bookcase*]

—John E. Warriner. Warriner’s English Grammar and Composition. Third Course. Liberty Edition. Orlando, Florida: Harcourt, Brace, and Jovanovich. 1986. 825.

CORRECT:

I was extremely surprised, and I am grateful for you all celebrating
 Mallory’s and my special day.