# British-English - My v Mine

Tags: british-english, possessives, possessive-pronouns, compound-possessives

I would like to know which of the options below is correct:

1. 'It is mine and John's favourite'
2. 'It is my and John's favourite'

Or if both are incorrect, what would be the correct way to phrase this?

Comment: Relevant previous questions: [What possessive forms are used for mutual 1st person ownership?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8520), [“Nikki's and Alice's X” vs. “Nikki and Alice's X”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849). It seems that there may be no generally accepted "correct" way to phrase this. You can reword to something like "John's favourite and mine".

Comment: A friend posted a song on social media and I wanted to comment 'That's mine and John's favourite song'... But wasn't sure if it should be my?

Comment: Another option is "John's and my favourite song"

Comment: Yes. I think that is the best option. All the others sounds a bit too pompous for social media 

Answer (score -3):

This structure is not used, for more than one reason.

Try instead,

> It's (a/the) favorite of John and I.

alt:

> It's (a/the) favorite of John's as also mine.

That said, songs can have their words and sentences whichever way the lyricist fancies.

### EDIT

> It was a favorite of John's and mine as well. We all shared a deep appreciation for Vonnegut's wonderfully wry and sardonic sci-fi classic, …

<sup>(Loren, et al., *High Notes: A Rock Memoir*, 2014, Google Books, [Ch.26](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=IfdZDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT195&lpg=PT195&dq=%22a%20favorite%20of%20john%27s%20and%20mine%22&source=bl&ots=m2Yk4Jl_tp&sig=YOMwleDz2-fc-zubiEyUBH3bUXw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwias6XAm4DdAhVFvo8KHUJ8CTcQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20favorite%20of%20john%27s%20and%20mine%22&f=false))</sup>

Comment: Traditionalist prescriptivists would object to "of John and I", and say that it should be "of John and me" because the coordinate noun phrase is the object of the preposition "of".

Comment: @sumelic Not everyone today writes for a traditionalist prescriptivist readership, though.

Comment: 'Traditionalist prescriptivists'? It's not not-traditional, it's just plain wrong. You wouldn't say 'favourite of I', so don't say 'favourite of John and I'.