# My/Mine to be used while writing email

Tags: single-word-requests

can I use----As per mine and John's understanding we concluded that...

Comment: << As per my understanding and John's understanding we concluded that... >>, and deleted to << As per my and John's understanding we concluded that... >>, but admittedly << As per John's understanding and mine we concluded that... >>.

Comment: I couldn't cite [British-English - My v Mine](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461199/british-english-my-v-mine) as a duplicate because it's got no upvoted answers, but that one specifically asks about the possessive pronoun choice in *It is **mine / my** and John's favourite*.

Comment: It's an ugly was to phrase , restructuring makes an easier read; "As far as John and myself understand, we conclude that ... "

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't: in that sentence, "my" is correct. An easy test: if you remove John, your sentence would read "As per mine understanding..." which is clearly not right.
Also -- and this is a stylistic, not grammatical, note -- avoiding "as per" at all costs is a wonderful contribution to better English. I'd write your sentence as "As John and I understood [or understand] it, we concluded that ..."