# Which is correct in this sentence: "me and my" or "my and my"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following sentences contains the grammatically correct bolded section:

"He affected **me and my** friend's day."
*or*
"He affected **my and my** friend's day."

It seems clear to me that the first sentence clearly sounds the best, but I was always told that you should be able to isolate the sentence to just one of the objects, i.e. remove my friend from the sentence, and when I do that, only the second sentence makes sense.

What is the correct grammar to use here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grammar and sentence structure check](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79494/grammar-and-sentence-structure-check)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "*He affected my day.*"
2. "*He affected my friend's day.*"
3. "*He affected my day and my friend's day.*"

Hence - "*He affected my and my friend's day.*"

You wouldn't think of writing - "*He affected me day.*" - would you? :)

> He affected me and my friend's day.

puts forward two things,

1. He affected you. (not your *day* but affected you in some other way)
2. He affected your friend's *day*.

Therefore, "*me and my*" is not a good combination for use in this context.

Comment: Thanks, that last part is exactly what I thought. :D  I saw your comment on the post before, and I was going to reply by saying that I had phrased the question wrong. To clarify, I had used "my and my" in writing that couldn't be changed (in a different sentence, and not in formal writing), and so I was looking to confirm that what I had used was correct. In hindsight, I would have certainly used your phrasing. Also, you needn't worry about editing your post any further, you have already been very helpful. :)

Comment: 'My friends' and my day'

Comment: @marcellothearcane - I doubt if the OP wants something like that. I myself thought up - "He affected my friend's day and mine." - but the OP actually just wants to know whether "my and my" or "me and my" is correct.

Comment: @marcellothearcane If you'll see my comment before you'll understand that as Justin said, I was indeed looking for which of the two was correct. Thanks for your help anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is both old and answered, but I would like to add something important.

Consider the following sentences:

> John and Mary's car broke down.
>
> John's and Mary's cars broke down.

Both sentences are correct, but they mean different things. In the first sentence, "John and Mary" are a unit that together own the car that broke down. In the second, "John" and "Mary" are two separate people with two separate cars.

In English, the genitive apostrophe-s ending is a lot more flexible than other endings (technically, it's what is known as a "clitic") and always appears at the end of the noun phrase. Hence,

> the man in the black hat's bobcat

rather than

> *"the man's in the black hat bobcat.

This does not change when discussing pronouns. The first question you should be asking yourself is

> Are I and my friend sharing this day that has been affected?

If your answer is "no", then Justin is correct - he has affected your and your friend's day**s**.

If your answer is "yes", then Justin's argument does not apply, and the proper question is

> Is it "me and my friend" or "I and my friend"?

Which is completely up to you, as English has no rules about whether to use "I" or "me" in this context.