# Is it she and James' or her and James'?

Tags: pronouns

The sentence is— "Her and James' life shouldn't be a topic of discussion for them." I believe that it should be she and James' and not her James'. Which version of the sentence is correct? Please help me out, thank you.

Comment: You wouldn't say "She life shouldn't be a topic of discussion", would you?

Comment: If their lives are considered separately, then **hers and James' lives** - if their shared life (e.g. as a couple) then **her and James' life** - or avoid the problem altogether by placing the name first **John's and her life/lives**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is correct in this sentence: "me and my" or "my and my"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508589/which-is-correct-in-this-sentence-me-and-my-or-my-and-my)

Comment: I would say "hers and James' lives..

Comment: Her and James' life together ended when they got divorced; hers and James' lives were saved when they were rescued from a sinking ship;  - or - James' and her life together ended when they got divorced; James' and her lives were saved when they were rescued from a sinking ship.

Comment: I am tempted to make a troll account to argue that, just as we say “for me” and “for her” but “for she and I”, here too it should be ”she”; and then log in as myself to downvote it.  But that would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is "Her and James' life shouldn't be a topic of discussion for them". It's "Her life" not "She life".