# Refer to something belonging to someone else and I

Tags: grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner)

How do I refer to something that belongs to both myself and someone else?

Example:
- My friend's and I's party.
- Mine and my friend's party.
- My friend's and my party.

I can't figure it out :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "our party" won't work for some reason, "my friend's and my party" is probably going to be the best you can do.