# Is “Paul’s and my ideas” *really* the correct possessive?

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns

Do you always have to put other people before yourself?

When you are telling a story about yourself and another person, it is correct to reference the other person first.  For example,

> Tim and I went shopping.

Given that rule, then is this also the case in the following type of sentence, where you’re forming a possessive of two people, one of whom is you yourself:

> Please see attached Paul's and my ideas on this subject.

This doesn't look at all right to me, but aside from rearranging the whole sentence I can't see how to make it right. Can I write:

> Please see attached myself/my/mine and Paul's ideas on this subject.

or does that go against the whole rule about putting the other person first?

I know I can make the sentence work by changing it around but I would like to know if there is a rule for this type of sentence.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, but you might find you will get better responses on our sister site [ell.se]

Comment: You could say "our ideas".

Comment: Note that [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8520) says that there are no acceptable solutions in formal written English. However, [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/25956) says otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your input. How do I close down this question?