# How do you casually describe in English a possession of thing(s) belonging to/shared by two people?

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, sentence-patterns

Neither of the following sounds quite "right" to me:

- This is the book of Kelly and I. (Maybe valid but still sounds too rigid)
- This book is of Kelly and mine's. (I know, sounds the weirdest)
- This is mine and Kelly's book.
- This book, Kelly and I own it.

In my native language (Indonesian) we have a phrase or a way of saying this without sounding weird or overly formal. Do you use any of the above at all, or is there any different sentence pattern for describing this kind of situation?

Comment: See *["Nikki's and Alice's X" vs. "Nikki and Alice's X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/nikkis-and-alices-x-vs-nikki-and-alices-x)* Also see *[What possessive forms are used for mutual 1st person ownership?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8520)* and *[“My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226)*, *[How do you make the possessive form with “He and I”-style subjects?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/38849/16052)*, and others.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any different sentence pattern for describing this kind of
>   situation?

Yes:

This book is **co-owned** by X and Y.  [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/co-owned)

> to own jointly with another

Comment: Thanks, I could definitely use this. Although I was looking for a more *casual* way of saying it (if any).

Answer (score -3):

A short answer:

This book belongs to Kelly and I.

In more depth: this is a case for compound possessive noun + pronoun:

- You do not add *'s* to the pronouns mine or my as it is already possessive (=I's)
- You add *'s* to the last noun preceding the pronoun

Thus, you'd say:

1. This book is Kelly's and mine.
2. This book is Claire, Kelly's and mine.
3. Kelly's and my book was gifted to us by Jordan.
4. Claire, Kelly's and my book was gifted to us by Jordan.

Comment: *This book belongs to Kelly and I.*  (I disagree with this). It is incorrect because you would not say "This book belongs to I" You should say, "This book belongs to me" and "This book belongs to Kelly and me."

Comment: @chaslyfromUK you are correct

Comment: Diane, thanks I appreciate this. Helps clearing my doubts! Although sentence #1 somehow makes more sense to me. @chaslyfromUK Noted. Thanks for clarifying that!