# Correct order of multiple possessive words

Tags: word-order, possessives

Which is correct:

> Myrtle’s party took place in her and Tom’s apartment

Or

> Myrtle’s party took place in Tom's and her apartment

Or neither?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is "my wife and I's" correct, or should it be "my wife's and my"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/is-my-wife-and-is-correct-or-should-it-be-my-wifes-and-my)

Comment: You should also include "Or either?"

Comment: @KitΘδς that Or between the two examples served that purpose, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this construction always appears slightly clunky; when I'm writing "x and y's" I always use the order of subject-first (so your sentence would read "Myrtle's party took place in her and Tom's apartment"). I wouldn't by default utilise brackets to separate 'her' and 'Tom'; it might be preferable to also introduce the second subject ("Tom") in a previous sentence in order for you to simply write "their apartment".

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd write : Myrtle's party took place in her (and Tom's) apartment.

Comment: Well in this case the fact that it's Tom's apartment is actually important and relevant and not just an extra fact.