# How to use the possessive form when referring to someone else and yourself?

Tags: possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is “my wife and I's” correct, or should it be “my wife's and my”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/is-my-wife-and-is-correct-or-should-it-be-my-wifes-and-my)

How to use the possessive form when referring to someone else and yourself?

For example, how could this awkward sentence be rephrased...

> We're all going to to the apartment which belongs to Christina and me.

... to use the possessive form? These don't sound/feel right...

> We're all going to Christina and me's apartment.
>
> We're all going to Christina and mine's apartment.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the reference to individuals with "our"

> We're all going to our apartment.

The problem is that "our" is not very specific, and the meaning depends on the context. The listeners would have to already know that the apartment belonged to you and Christina.

You could also modify the second option to be less awkward sounding:

> We're all going to mine and Christina's apartment.

You could also maybe use:

> We're all going to Christina's and my apartment

Comment: The word is "my". It should be "Christina's and my apartment." You wouldn't say "We're all going to mine apartment."

Comment: @Peter Shor: I didn't think `my` would be correct in this case, except as "We're all going to Christina's and my apartment".

Comment: I think "my and Christina's apartment" would also be grammatical, but it sounds a little funny to me, since usually "my", "I", and "me" come last.

Comment: "Mine and Christina's apartment" is incorrect. If you want to put "my" first, and you think (as I do) that "my and Christina's apartment" sounds a little funny, you can always say "the apartment I and Christina share."