# How to use "my" correctly in a plural possessive?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “my wife and I's” correct, or should it be “my wife's and my”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/is-my-wife-and-is-correct-or-should-it-be-my-wifes-and-my)

Are the following sentences grammatically correct? If not, how should I correct them? This situation has always tripped me up, since "me and (noun)'s (noun)" is the common slang way to speak.

> My wife's and my anniversary is on Saturday.

Or another example:

> Patrick's and my bathroom is painted red.

Comment: We've seen this question before, and yes, those are correct.