# Lack of possessive marker when taken from a group

Tags: possessives

I'm confused by this sentence:

> One of my best friends band is playing tonight.

What is it that happens here, is the possessive marker completely dropped?

From what I understand:

- I can't add an 's since "one of" refers to the group of friends
- I can't add s' (friends') since the band is only one person's band.

Comment: Easily fixed by *My best friend's band* if you are not tied to the unfixable structure you created, and you don't worry that someone may suspect you have no other best friends.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I see that I can fix it, I'm more interested in if this can be the correct way to say it in its current form, and if so, why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The queen of England's crown" or "The queen's of England crown"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92506/the-queen-of-englands-crown-or-the-queens-of-england-crown) and previously mentioned at ['My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think so, since none of them involves a group?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth or from the first one, does it mean that I can write:
"One of my best friends' band is playing tonight" ?

Comment: "Easily fixed" means something *needs fixing*, because it's not correct the way it is.

Comment: Yes. ''The Queen of England's crown'' = ''The crown of the Queen of England''. ''One of my best friends' band'' = ''The band of one of my best friends''.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth alright, if you put that as an answer I'll put it as the accepted one.

Comment: But we don't want a duplicate of an earlier question. It just adds bloat and makes searches harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English is fairly malleable, but it is still possible to paint yourself into a corner. One area this crops up is where a writer tries to make a word function in incompatible ways - such as being singular and plural simultaneously.

What’s happening in your example is that the “s” in “friends” can’t be coerced to do double duty to mark a plural (my friends) as well as a singular (one friend’s band).

There are several ways around this, one of which is to use a different syntax for the genitive / possessive: “the band *of* one of my friends ...”.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.

Comment: ''One of my best friends' band'' is as acceptable as ''the Queen of England's crown''. The whole NP (or whatever) is treated as if it were a noun. "The boy in the glasses' laptop".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There is no singular/plural tension in your example.

Comment: ''One of my best friends' band'' = ''The band of one of my best friends''. "The Lord of the Isles' family crest". The apostrophe (where pronunciation requires it with an s) goes after the NP. 'Singular/plural tension' doesn't arise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I guess you can argue that numerical agreement is already determined by the head noun, so the apostrophe convention becomes less important.

Comment: Logic? In English? It's just one area I've never seen an alternative claim about. Of course, if/where clarity becomes an issue, I'd always rephrase (or, until a Grammar/Punctuation ... Czar crowns themself and uses force to get compliance use something non-standard) if I couldn't see another way round a problem [without writing an essay].