# Chained possessive words

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“My wife and I’s seafood collaboration dinner”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner)

I’m sure there are better ways to write the following sentence, but I was curious to know if this sentence is grammatically correct:

> Every day, Mike would send letters to Sarah and Thomas’s daughters’ boyfriends.

My hunch is that the apostrophe placement is incorrect. The idea is that Mike is sending letters to the daughters of Sarah and Thomas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s grammatical, but ambiguous. Did he send letters to Sarah and to the boyfriends of the daughters of Thomas, or did he send letters to the boyfriends of the daughters of Sarah and Thomas? If the former, it might be better expressed as

> Every day, Mike would send letters to Sarah. He would also send them
>   to the boyfriends of Thomas's daughters.

If the latter,

> Every day, Mike would send letters to the boyfriends of Sarah’s and
>   Thomas's daughters.

If Sarah and Thomas are the parents of the same daughters, it might be best put as

> Every day, Mike would send letters to the boyfriends of the daughters
>   of Sarah and Thomas.

but even that would depend on the context.

Comment: Is it really really ambiguous? It seems to me that the ambiguity is essentially an invention of grammar pedants. In reality, if you say "to Sarah and Thomas'(s) daughter", you fairly unambiguously mean the daughter of the couple [Sarah and Thomas]. Otherwise, people would tend to say "to Sarah and to Thomas('s) daughter". (And in pronunciation, it is entirely unambiguous.)

Comment: @Neil Coffey. Perhaps, but _Sarah and Thomas' daughters' boyfriends_ is still a cumbersome way of putting it. In practice, it would probably occur as something like _You know Sarah and Thomas? Well, their daughters had boyfriends at the time, and what do you think? That Mike - you know, the one I told you about - he sent the boyfriends letters every day, apparently. What do you make of that?_

Comment: Yes - the example seems contrived anyway - surely the daughters would have been introduced in a prior sentence.