# If I am saying "Someone and Myself's (possession)", what would the correct usage in this phrase be?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, american-english

I was just wondering how to properly use the phrase, I am trying to talk about something that belongs to both my friend and myself so how would I say that? My friend and myself's? or a different way?

Comment: This question may already have an answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/is-my-wife-and-is-correct-or-should-it-be-my-wifes-and-my

Comment: I would like to point out that there is a difference between “Jim and John’s ideas” and “Jim’s and John’s ideas”.  In the first case, the ideas are shared between them, and in the second one, they are not.  That is another application of the Saxon genitive applying to the whole phrase, as in “(Jim and John)’s ideas”: it distributes.

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be to give a heads on to the audience (to the people you are talking to) by introducing the fact that you and your friend are related to the object together. 
And then you can go on using 'OUR' or 'We' in the subsequent sentences. E.g.:

> Me and my friend ABC just bought this really cool toy. Our toy is the best toy in the world. We play with our toy all the time. We don't want to sell it off.

Sorry for the lame example!

Comment: Do you mean, "My friend and *I* just bought..."?