# Is this wrong? "What are each of them's objections?"

Tags: grammar

Let's say I've put forward an idea to a number of people and each person has several different objections to it.

I know I can say:

> What are each individual's objections?
>   
> - OR -
>   
> What are the objections for each of them?

But can I say:

> What are each of them's objections?

It sounds awkward, but is it wrong? I don't want to say:

> What are each of their objections?

Because the "their" in that sentence refers to all the people and therefore all the objections. What I want is to ask for the objections grouped by person.

Also can I say:

> What are each's objections?

Comment: No, the possessive of "them" is not "them's", it's "their".

Comment: No You can't say *them's* or *each's*. The reason you give for not using *their* makes sense, but that reason no longer applies once  you have changed it to *each of their objections* (as you have suggested). Least ambiguous would be *each person's objections*.

Comment: @Marthaª the possessive of *them* is *their*, but the possessive of *each of them* is not *each of their*. "Each of them's" is, of course, nonstandard, but other than that it's perfectly fine, which is why people produce it in the first place. [We've covered that before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner).

Comment: The problem is that the possessive suffix cliticizes to the end of the noun phrase _each of them_, and saying _each of their_ doesn't capture that bracketing correctly: _each of their objections_ is parsed as [each [of their objections]] instead of [[each of their] objections].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to structure this statement will not only depend on the goal of the statement itself, but also on the body of text which surrounds it. In all cases, you must indicate who "they" or "them" are, either in this statement or another. Since here, I assume you are referring to a group of individuals, such must be identified in close proximity.

To directly answer your question, "them's" and 'each's" are not possessive forms, so no.

One suggestion might be:

What are the objections of each individual?

or

What are the objections of each? (Depending on how the individual was defined in the preceding text)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that, in the same way that 'anyone' is to 'any', 'each one' can be to 'each', so the following constructions probably provide the most succinct way of saying that you want a response giving objections listed against each person:

What are each one's objections? 
What are the objections for each one?

'Each' can be a pronoun as well as an adjective or adverb, but it appears that it doesn't have a possessive form, even though 'each's' is permissible according to standard English grammar - in the same way that you can create a past participle out of a verb infinitive by adding '-ed', as a *weak* verb, unless there is a *strong* verb alternative. As there is no *strong* alternative for the possessive of each, there's nothing stopping you putting an apostrophe 's' after 'each' to create a possessive form, except for it sounding awkward because it is not a form one hears in practice. The only thing that *does* stop you therefore is its strangeness on the ear, and grammar zealots stopping the evolution of the language!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could use
"What are each of your objections?"

If you use "each of them" you are referring to the individuals, not the objections that belong to them.  Their is the plural possessive. Them is the objective case of the pronoun they.
"Them's objections" wouldn't be grammatical.

Comment: -1 Your answer changes the person to whom the question is addressed: *you* instead of *them*. What's wrong with *each of their objections* as proposed by OP?

Comment: Nothing, but op stated that he or she would not like to use it, so I simply provided an alternative.

Comment: OP *actually* asked "Can I say: ...?" about certain phrases.

Comment: Please see the following quote regarding op's preference to not use 'each of their objections'." I don't want to use: What are each of their objections?

Because the "their" in that sentence refers to all the people and therefore all the objections. What I want is to ask for the objections grouped by person."       
In this case, because the op specifically states that the focus should be on each individual and not the group, using "your" would be a viable alternative.  Finally op did not ask about the correctness of "each of their", but instead stated that he or she wished not to use it.