# Question about the Possessive with Multiple Parties

Tags: grammar, possessives

Suppose I want to refer to the widget owned by me and Susan.

Then do I say "you are welcome to use Susan's and my widget"? (Sounds awkward.)

Or "you are welcome to use the widget owned by Susan and I"? (Too long, clunky.)

How do I say this correctly? I would prefer not to rearrange the phrase altogether to avoid the problem. How do I correctly format the possessive with the multiple parties?

Comment: I read recently that the convention is to make only the last noun/pronoun possessive (I think it was in the NYT style guide). So it would be *Susan and my widget*. You will doubtless get another opinion.

Comment: @Susan In certain cases, such as the one in question, this construction is **perilous** -- please read the whole sentence again and see for yourself.

Comment: If Susan is correct, could I then say without peril "Please use Susan and my gadget for your personal pleasure" ??

Comment: "... Susan's and my widget" I have been using this structure for ages, and I've never felt awkward about it.

Comment: @Kris - ah. Thank you. It is like the Oxford comma then, and subject to unintended (disastrous but funny) meaning. I stand corrected.

Comment: Very closely related: [My wife and I's](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner).

Comment: Our widget.  Why list all the owners all the time?

Answer (score 2):

Just technically thinking, the possible option to avoid pitfalls could be:

> You are welcome to use me-and-Susan's widget

- Okay, protocol gone, *fpp* before others, but it works.
- Hyphenate to disambiguate: the widget is joint property.
- Now that there's just a compound noun, just one possessive should do.

There *can* be other, better ways to do it.

Comment: klugy, kludgy, ke-loo-gie

Comment: +1 - I upvoted your answer as perfectly reasonable. Blessed Geek's comment is, however, hilarious.

Comment: Me's widget is acceptable?

Comment: @Oldcat I'm not sure about 'acceptability', but that just doesn't exist: *mine*, not *me's*, (even in "x and me"?).

Comment: @Susan klugy, yes, I said as much: "but it works". Now, what's the joke, please?