# The possessive s

Tags: grammar, possessives

My problem is about the possessive s (the *ownership s*) not that *ending-s*.

For example, we say, *America's Flag*, here the *America* has gotten one *ownership s* that is *America* is the owner of that *Flag*. And also we say, *Computer Science*, here that *Computer* doesn't get the *ownership s* (why?) even though we talk about *Science* which is of *Computer* (here).

My question is when we should add that *s* to the end of the first name which appear to be the owner of the second name? Or how we can recognize what names get that *s*, please?

Comment: This is probably a better question for ELL, but in short it's because America is a noun and Computer is acting as an adjective here. America can own things, but Computer as an adjective cannot

Comment: This question would feel better at home on our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell/stackexchange.com)

Comment: I would say the American flag and not America's flag

Comment: I think this question is suitable here on EL&U and since it was asked here, there is no reason to migrate it.

Comment: So glad I broke up with *s*, she was super possessive. And she always had that Apostrophe guy hanging around, too. Still, I hope she doesn't contract something bad from him.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner)

Comment: Possible duplicate/cross-posted on ELL: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26543/the-ownership-s

Answer (score 11):

That is because *computer* is used adjectival to *science*.

You could say that the [noun *computer* "acts as" an *adjective*](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm).

It is the same thing that happens in other compound nouns, like

> history teacher
>   ticket office
>   race horse

Actually, the science does not belong to the computer (my computer is unable to show me any science that it possesses!) but rather, the *science* is *about computers*.

Whenever in doubt, ask yourself if you are actually expressing *ownership*. If not, there is no s:

> John's store is a candy store. (John *owns* the store, candy does *not* own the store.)
>   Pete's prize is the Nobel Prize. (Pete won the prize, but Nobel gave his name to it)

Comment: English didn't always work this way; before 1900 it could have been *historical teacher* and *computational science*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=history+teacher%2Chistorical+teacher&year_start=1850&year_end=1900&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chistory%20teacher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chistorical%20teacher%3B%2Cc0) (but still *ticket office* and *race horse*).

Comment: @oerkelens: Thanks for your answer, but, a question: Consider these two, _Government road_ and _Bank's computer_. I don't know how to determine which one (_Government_ or _Bank_) should give that _s_.

Comment: Does the road _belong_ to the government, or is it _named after_ it? Does "Bank" _own_ the computer, or is it a computer designed in a "Bank" way?

Comment: Why the _road_ doesn't belong to the _government_!? It does I think.

Comment: Yeah, as in "the government owns everything". But then you shoul name all roads the same. The _reason_ to call it "government road" is not that it _belongs_ to the government, but you name it in honour of the government. Or possibly, because of a major government building being located there. Compare to "Station street". Not owned by the station, but the station is _probably_ somewhere on the street.

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean. It's not clear for me. But, I appreciate your trying to help me. Probably there isn't any general and obvious rule for that!

Comment: Yes, the rule is clear and obvious! Say that my name is John, and I _buy_ a road. Then that road becomes John's road. That is _not_ the _name_ of the road, it just says that it is _my property_. Now, I may _name_ the road "Mary Road", without the possessive. I name the street after her, I do not _give it to her. You only use a possessive s to indicate that something or someone _possesses_ something. A computer does not _possess computer science, a race does not _possess_ a race horse, Mandela does not _possess_ Mandela Square. in all those cases, you do not use a possesive s.

Comment: @user3724662 - it is better to move his to the ELL version of this question anyway, because it really fits better there. If needed, I will expand my answer there to make it clearer :)

Comment: OK, I move there.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of Computer Science, the science doesn't belong to a computer.  The word "computer" here is being used as a modifier - effectively an adjective - to make the word science more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Indefinite names don't get possessive s (the ownership s).

Like Computer Science. (Computer is indefinite).

Definite names (like proper names) get possessive s (the ownership s).

Like America's Flag. (America is Definite).

---

Edits:

"What about "the cat's pajamas"? –  Samuel Edwin Ward"

Me: Well, the cat is definite name, because you use "the" article before that.

Comment: This isn't the whole answer (which is quite complicated and subtle) but it captures the important point.

Comment: What about "the cat's pajamas"?

Comment: what about the comment I put under the answer of "oerkelens"?