# What is enough to qualify for ownership in the use of the genitive?

Tags: saxon-genitive

In some cases it is crystal clear, for instance in

> my mother's nose

the nose clearly belongs to my mother.

In cases where the name is adjectival, it also makes sense not to use it.

But what is "enough" to qualify for ownership in that case ? What about the parking spot of your car ? Would you say

> your car's parking spot ?

or

> your car parking spot ?

and why ? In [this old thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178548/the-possessive-s) I saw a mention of

> Indefinite names don't get possessive s.

I know such things as definite/indefinite articles, but I didn't know this principle transferred to nouns (does it even?). And in the previous example, I used "**your** car" where your is a possessive adjective, is it enough to know which car we are talking about in particular to qualify for a possessive even though we didn't use a definite article ?

Since "your car" is an inanimate object, can it even possess anything ?

Comment: The possessive relationship indicated by the apostrophe not only denotes true possession (e.g. _Mary's car_), but also relationships (e.g. _Mary's sister_), measurements (_a minute's thought_), partitives (_the book's pages_), and others. Here is a similar question to yours about "_the car/'s parking spot_": https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/413353/any-complete-rule-on-the-usage-of-s-for-possession

Comment: There are many related questions; see also [the list here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33095/possessive-connecting-word-for-inanimate-object).

Comment: I could refer to my car's ***position***, and to be honest I find that far more natural than talking about my car's parking spot (it's ***my*** parking spot, not my car's! :) But it's often not particularly helpful to think about "possession, ownership" in the context of the Saxon Genitive / possessive apostrophe.

Comment: Genitive is the marked relation between nouns; it comes up when, for instance, a verb phrase is transformed into a noun phrase: _the woman ran_ becomes _the running of the woman_ without going through any "possession" -- the _of_ simply marks the noun that would be the intransitive subject. If the verb phrase were transitive (_the woman ran the race_) then the _of_ would mark the object (like an intransitive subject, a transitive object is absolutive, not ergative). Transitive agent subjects are ergative and they take _by_, not _of_: _The running of the race by the woman_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is using the possessive 's correct in "the car's antenna"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/is-using-the-possessive-s-correct-in-the-cars-antenna)

Comment: I can't upvote your comments but they are helpful, thank you. The first one especially since it comes with some good examples.