# Parenthesis and apostrophes

Tags: commas, possessives, apostrophe, parentheses

If there is a noun, then parenthesis or a comma, where should a `'s` go? For example:

> The dog (who was very big)'s ears perked up.

or

> The dog's (who was very big) ears perked up.

or

> The dog's, who was very big, ears perked up.

or maybe just:

> The very big dog's ears perked up.

Comment: The dog's ears (and he was very big) perked up.

Comment: What Edwin Ashworth says. This is trying to make the language do something she doesn't want.

Comment: In *speech* you can just about get away with things like *"[The man I married's](http://open.salon.com/blog/straight-no-chaser_mom/2012/07/19/mule_not_mewl) father said he always was as obstinate as a mule"*, because you can indicate by prosody/cadence that *the-man-I-married* is a "compound noun" being treated as a single lexical unit to be modified by genitive **'s**. But without resorting to hyphenation, it's often difficult to make this usage work in a written context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And in this case the relative clause is specifically designated as parenthetical, i.e. non-restrictive, so it's not part of the constituent.

Comment: @StoneyB: As Kosmonaut says in a very closely related question, [people may have different opinions about which of these types of constructions they would allow](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/22073/2637) (to be "collectively" modified by the Saxon genitive). But my guess is that almost all native speakers would be at least *slightly* more accepting of whatever they consider "marginal" usages in speech rather than in writing.

Comment: Why is everyone making such a fuss over the ears of a *dog?* It's not like he's a fox or something.

Comment: @Erik: Quite. And as StoneyB points out, it's not like this particular dog is *uniquely* identified by its size. Nevertheless, as OP awkwardly informs us, it is ***very big***. So it's not like we're making a fuss over something insignificant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first one is questionable.

Your second two are justifiable, but awkward. They're probably the closest thing to an answer to the question of "what is the correct way to use a parenthetical clause about a subject while using the subject in the genitive?" but they're still awkward.

Your last does the best by rephrasing to make the issue go away.

So too would:

> The dog's ears perked up.

In-between those two ways of avoiding the issue entirely would be:

> The dog's ears (he was very big) perked up.
>
> The dog's ears (and he was very big) perked up.
>
> The dog's ears perked up. He was very big.

Comment: "The dog's ears ([and] he was very big) perked up" seems quite awkward to me, especially in spoken language.