# This is my, Tom, and Alex's poster which we made for last Monday's lesson

Tags: word-choice

Is this right?

How do I show ownership by the group of three of us?

Comment: What is it you’re trying to say?

Comment: I'm showing someone a poster which myself and classmates made for the lesson last monday

Comment: The OP appears to be asking how to indicate three-way ownership in a single sentence, and asking if "This is my, Tom and Alex's poster [...]" is gramatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

> This is the poster which Tom, Alex, and I made for last Monday's lesson.

Note that "polite" style is to place yourself last in a list such as is used above.

Answer (score 0):

The correct construction would be, "This is my, Tom's, and Alex's poster, which we made for last Monday's lesson." However, there are more effective ways to write it.

> This poster, which we made for last Monday's lesson, is Tom's, Alex's and mine.
>
> This poster was made for last Monday's lesson by Tom, Alex, and me.
>
> Tom, Alex and I made this poster for last Monday's lesson.

However, as [the answers to this question suggest](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner), you could also write, informally, "This is Tom, Alex and I's poster." Note that while this may be accepted in speech, it looks and reads very strangely.

Answer (score 0):

This is the poster Tom, Alex and I made for last Monday's lesson.

This is our poster. Tom, Alex and I made it for last Monday's lesson.

This is our (Tom, Alex, and myself) poster which we made for last Monday's lesson.

While the example sentence might fill out a sentence diagram without errors, it sounds stilted to my ear.

If the question is simply about how could you communicate ownership by 3 people, I offer the above suggestions.

If the question is really about the technical correctness of the sentence in the title, post a comment and Ill delete this answer.