# Which is correct here, "your" or "yours"?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, determiners

I know that

- "Your" is a determiner and,
- "Yours" is a possessive pronoun.

I had a case where I wasn't sure if it should be used as a determiner or pronoun:

> In response from **your and someone's answers**

OR

> In response from **yours and someone's answers**

Which was the correct use?

Comment: It's "response **to**..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your* is a **possessive adjective**:

> *Your* raincoat is red.

Whereas *yours* is a **possessive pronoun**:

> That raincoat of *yours* is red.

*Yours*, the possessive pronoun is used to refer to a thing or things belonging to or associated with the person or people that the speaker is addressing.

---

With your example phrase:

> *In response from your and someone's answers.*

You could say:

> In response to *your* and someone's answer, it could be concluded that....

or alternatively:

> In response to someone's answer and [also] *yours*, it could be concluded that...

With the latter example, the possesive pronoun *yours* is referring to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To stick with the distinction between possessive pronoun vs. determiner, consider this excellent description offered by [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc):

> We use pronouns to refer to possession and ‘belonging’. There are two types: possessive pronouns and possessive determiners. We use **possessive determiners before a noun**. We use **possessive pronouns in place of a noun**

They provide this example:

> Is that [determiner] **your** scarf? It’s very similar to [pronoun] **mine**

They also offer this advice with an example:

> **Don’t use possessive pronouns before nouns**
>
> Lots of **our** friends were at the party.
>
> **Not**: Lots of **ours** friends …

It's understandable that the two can be confused, since they can both replace a Proper noun.  Consider these examples:

> The apple is **yours**. (*possessive pronoun*)
>
> This is **your** apple. (*determiner*)

In either case, the word could be replaced with "Alice's."

> The apple is **Alice's**.
>
> This is **Alice's** apple.

The structure of the sentence in the question takes the form of the latter, where "your" functions as a determiner.  Remember, as Cambridge recommended, you don't use a possessive pronoun before a noun.  In the example given, "answers" is a noun, so you would use a determiner, not a possesive pronoun.

> In response to **your** answers

and not

> In response to **yours** answers

The fact that you are adding another person to the equation doesn't affect this use (with the exception of a caveat I'll get to in a moment).  You still would write

> In response to **your** and Alice's answers

The caveat is, as was pointed out in the other answer, this is still a somewhat awkward phrasing, and it could be rephrased "In response to **you** and **Alice's** answers," just like you might write "In response to **Steve** and **Alice's** answers." But if you want to adhere to the structure in the question, you can't go wrong following the guidelines provided by Cambridge.  Since "your" modifies "answers," it functions as a determiner.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that John is the other person, so we are talking about your answers and about John’s.  Because the clitic falls at the end of the entire noun phrase it is modifying, here *you and John*, the correct form here should be something more along these lines:

> In response to you and John’s answers, I have decided to award you both the first prize.

Because combining first or second person possessives with third person ones is always going to sound awkward<sup>([see this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4226))</sup>, I would rewrite to avoid this:

> In response to the answers from both you and John, I have decided to award the two of you the first prize in this contest.

Comment: What if instead of "someones" it was the persons name... i.e. In response to yours and Peter's  answers, I have decided to award  you both first place. ?

Comment: @Luke That’s a good question. The combined noun phrase of *you and Luke* would take an apostrophe-s at the end. This is pretty awkward.

Comment: This answer deserves more downvotes. [This graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+and+his%2C+your+and+his&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) might make you *think* that the normal form was *you and John's answer* but those don't actually go together at all. The graph is actually showing [*you* and *some person of John's*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+and+his+*%2Cyour+and+his+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) are what's being joined. *You* and *John's answer* don't go together at all...

Comment: ...unless something like *you and John's answer are both mistaken* is what's being intended. Even there, you're right, it's awkward and should be reworded.

Comment: For all those instances of *you*, why would we not expect … you and John’s answers to be exactly equivalent to … John’s and you answers…, please?