# How would you write the possessive with yourself and another person?

Tags: possessives, compound-possessives

How would you write the possessive with **yourself** and another person?

For example:

> Would you like to join Bob's and my group?

Comment: I would do my very best to avoid it. "Bob's and my group" vs. "my and Bob's group"? There's not much to choose between them. Both are pretty awful.

Comment: "Bob and I have a group; would you like to join it?"

Answer (score -2):

Would you like to join Bob and I's group? This states the two of you as a noun phrase, and while sumelic's link below shows the controversy surrounding its usage, I find that is is the most efficient phrasing.

Comment: "I's" sounds horrible to many people. "I" is a nominative pronoun, so it shouldn't normally be able to occur in a non-subject noun phrase. See comments and answers here: [“My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226)