# What is the correct way to write multiple possessives, rather than the common way?

Tags: compound-possessives

In the phrase, "Tim Rice and Andrew Lloyd Webber's *Jesus Christ Superstar*...," I believe Rice should end in 's, as Webber does, because the show is as much Rice's as it is his partner's. However, whenever I've seen multiple nouns in a possessive, the first noun does not have thhe 's. I cannot fine a grammar rule to address this. Is it a case in which people have written and said it wrong for so long, the incorrect use has become acceptable? Which use is correct?

Comment: Peanut butter and jelly's advantage is its simplicity, not _their_ simplicity. Same with Tim Rice and Andrew Lloyd Webber's musicals, the team's results were stellar. No need to say that Rice's contribution was mostly words and Webber mostly music.

Comment: @MDHunter: That question has the added complication of dealing with pronouns, and it also seems to be asking for an explanation of the *non-standard* structure (see [RegDwigнt♦'s comment here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner#comment173119_86817)) while this question is asking about what is standard.

Answer (score 0):

Just the apostrophe-s at the end.  Looking to how people usually refer to such work, I can find multiple instance of "X and Y's creation," but none of "X's and Y's creation."  Examples

> Rodgers and Hammerstein's Cinderella ([link](http://cinderellaonbroadway.com/)), Rodgers and Hammerstein's *Carousel* ([link](http://Rodgers%20and%20Hammerstein%E2%80%99s%20Carousel)), Rodgers and Hammerstein's *Oklahoma!* ([link](http://www.pbs.org/wnet/gperf/rodgers-hammersteins-oklahoma-full-episode/1938/)), Gilbert and Sullivan's 'Princess Ida' ([link](http://www.thecrimson.com/article/1955/2/25/gilbert-and-sullivans-princess-ida-palthough/)).

Comment: You are the very model of a modern major general.