# Complicated Possessive?

Tags: compound-possessives

Is "Daddy, me and the dog's favourite activity" correct?

<s>Cos</s> Because technically it's "Daddy, the dog and me's favourite activity", right?

Comment: Similar to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner, possible duplicate

Comment: It is only convention that has us put the personal pronoun last in a list—and only out of perceived politeness (where we mention other people before us). There is nothing ungrammatical about listing yourself first. But it's not clear if it's the order of the pronouns you're questioning, or the specific syntax.

Answer (score 1):

'It is **my** favourite activity'. 'It is **Daddy's** favourite activity'. 'It is **the dog's** favourite activity' are all correct.

'Me's' is not. The possessive form of 'me' is 'mine'.

But you get into trouble if you try to combine these thoughts into a single sentence constructed the way you have. You could say 'It is Daddy's, **my** and the dog's favourite activity'.

That sounds really odd, though, if all you mean is 'Daddy, the dog and I all like ... most of all'.

Comment: Answer is correct. But, I prefer the term Daddy, the dog and my favorite.  Flows better.