# What's the proper grammar for "My and my roommate's home..."?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-case, saxon-genitive, coordinating-conjunctions

What's the proper grammar for "My and my roommate's home..."

The rule I learned is it should still be grammatically correct after removing the second part. E.g. after removing "and my roommate's", "My home..." is still valid. However, even though I'm a native speaker, "My and my roommate's home..." sounds weird. Is this rule correct?

---

<sup>NB with regards to ["My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner) , that question is only tangentially related, as the rule I've asked about doesn't apply. Nobody says "I's seafood dinner"!</sup>

Comment: I would avoid the problem by just saying "my home" and not mentioning the roommate.

Comment: If I *had* to say something without rephrasing it significantly, I'd say *me and my roommate's home*, turning it into the possessive of a compound (objective) noun. (E.g, *The home belongs to **me and my roommate**.*)

Comment: My house, which I share with my roommate, ...

Comment: Hi Leo, I've done a minor edit on your post as it had attracted a couple of close-votes. If you don't like the edit for any reason, please feel free to role it back.

Comment: Strictly speaking, _My and my roommate's home_ **is** correct, for the reason you give. If you want to be more colloquial you can follow @JasonBassford's advice.

Comment: There's another (non-strict) rule, which all of these suggestions are violating, which is that when referencing the first person in a list, it appears last.

Comment: Would *my roommate's and my* be less weird?