# Alice and mine's office?

Tags: grammar

Is this correct:

"This is the view from Alice and mine's office"

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner)

Comment: No, that does not answer his question, I'm afraid. "My wife and I" forms the subject of the sentence in the quote you provide, so the phrase is a nominative subject, whereas "Alice and mine" are in the objective case, in that they follow the conjunction "from". (I would actually paraphrase, and say "This is the view from the office belonging to / which belongs to both Alice and me.")

Comment: Yes it looks wonky and can be rephrased, but is it correct?

Comment: Of course not. You wouldn't  say _mine's office_, would you? To find the correct version, simply say it _without_ mentioning the other person.

Comment: So ... "Alice's and my office"

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is correct, and it sounds clunky on the tongue.
I think the correct way to say it is, "This is the view from Alice's and my office."

The suggestion from @theadvocate in the comments is good, you could also try:

"This is the view from our office, he said looking over at Alice."
"Alice and I love the view from our office."

Comment: You'd have a better answer if you explained why "Alice and my office" is correct.

Comment: True enough, if I only knew. Like a musician who learned how to play music by ear, I'm a writer who learned how to write by instinct, not by instruction.

Comment: It isn't correct. It's _Alice's and my office_..

Comment: @Kate Bunting - Thank goodness for someone who understands English. I was beginning to think I was the only one!

Comment: @KateBunting, you are correct, I should have reread my response. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a rule* for such things but the problem here is that it produces ambiguous results.
2. What do we actually **say** in English? (British in my case)

*This is the view from the office that belongs to Alice and me*

or

*This is the view from the office belonging to Alice and me*

---

*It is just the usual rule. Use each term separately, without the "and" and see what you get. Then combine using "and".

"This is the view from Alice's office."

"This is the view from my office."

"This is the view from Alice's and my office."

---

Note: If you wish to downvote, please also give a reason. Thanks.

Comment: There's no excuse for a high-rep user answering an obvious and obviously well-answered duplicate already flagged as such.