# What is the grammatically correct way of attributing possession to the noun phrase "her and others"?

Tags: grammaticality

"I also felt an urgent need to be able to do more to directly impact **her and others’ lives** during..."

Is the bold part grammatically correct? Should it be "her and others' life"? Do I need to break it up and say "her life and the lives of others"?

Comment: Personally I would make both references to people posessive giving "... _hers_ and _others'_ lives...". This isn't a bad idea even when dealing with words which both have the same plural, for example "...Ali's and Jack's cars are parked in the driveway..." but when the posessive forms are different it removes a lot of ambiguity.

Comment: The sentence is a poor one. It includes three infinitives in quick succession, the third of which is split, and a phrasal verb - **impact on** which, as this [note on usage](https://www.lexico.com/definition/impact) at Lexico explains, is often avoided. Here are some alternatives:  *affect, influence, have an effect on, transform, shape, control.* **"her and others' lives"** is not grammatically wrong, but perhaps **"her life and the lives of others"** is more elegant.

Comment: PS There's a good answer to the posessive question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner) at StackExchange

Comment: @Old Brixtonian +1 for the << "her and others' lives" is not grammatically wrong, but perhaps "her life and the lives of others" is more elegant >> but -1 for the worry about 'to directly impact'.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. Your question would be what in North America is often called “great” for a site dedicated to advice on creative writing, but this site specifically designates this (“proof reading”) as off-topic. It also is a matter of subjective opinion — also off-topic. I could rewrite your sentence, but to learn for yourself I suggest you study word use and sentence structure in John Bunyan’s “Pilgrim’s Progress”. After that you may leave impact to the dental profession. Ok try “to have a direct effect on her life and the lives of others..”

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: It's a harsh world. A +1 cruelly snatched away! It was *Lexico* who said that use of 'impact' was often avoided. I think the same might be said of split infs, don't you? When speaking, do you split them? Do you split them *without noticing*?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't know where you read that "it is me" was originally correct, but i think it's a myth. That argument about Latin was used to bolster arguments in favor of keeping outdated grammar in the face of a changing language, not in favor of changing English grammar to something entirely new. Shakespeare never used *it is me* or *'tis me*, but used *it is I* and *'tis I* eight times — for example, "it is I // That all the abhorred things o' the earth amend // By being worse than they."

Comment: @Peter Shor I'll retract To OB:  Do you get a mild shock every time you use 'It's me'? (Apparently a 'correct' form until a Latin fan imposed a pseudo-rule 200 or so years ago, and now back in favour.) '[_It is I_ or _It is me_?] Both forms have existed for centuries, with it is me tending to appear in more relaxed contexts even long ago.... you ... can choose whichever you prefer whenever you like.' [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/it-is-i-or-it-is-me-predicate-nominative-usage-guide)]

Comment: @OldBrixtonian You corrected if beautifully, however, "her and others' lives" cannot possibly be grammatical.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks! I wouldn't **say** it but I don't see "her and others' lives" as ungrammatical. I think we'd all *prefer* to rewrite such an ugly sentence, but what would you say/write? Edwin Ashworth seemed to think it was OK (above, near the top) and as far as I can tell, Fowler (see my new answer) *seems* to agree, though I wish he had an example using "<i>others</i>.

Answer (score 1):

I know Fowler was writing a hundred years ago but, as there are still no generally-agreed rules about two possessives in a row, maybe his words are still helpful.

From **The King's English:**

> *"I am not sure yours and my efforts would suffice separately; but
> yours and mine together cannot possibly fail."*
> The first *yours* is quite wrong; it should be **your**.

And

> *"You altered the succession to theirs, as well as to your own crown."* — Burke.
>
> We might possibly tolerate **to their as well as to your own;** or we might write **to their crown as well as to your own**.

From **A Dictionary of Modern English Usage**:

> A mistake is often made when two or more possessives are to be
> referred to a single noun that follows. The correct forms are: **your
> and our and his effort**s (not *yours and ours*); **either my or your
> informant must have lied** (not *mine*); **her and his mutual
> dislike** (not *hers*). 
>  There is no doubt a natural temptation to
> substitute the wrong word; the simple possessive seems to pine at
> separation from its property. The true remedy is a change of order:
> **your efforts and ours and his; my informant or yours; our help without yours**. It is not always available, however; **her and his
> mutual dislike** must be left as it is.